# how I can get the real-time progress bar in BeautifulSoup python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, progress-bar

I have the following code and the code scrapes some data from websites like Redbubble. and sometimes I scrape a lot of data and I want to know the real-time progress in the code... I tried progressbar module but I didn't get what I want....

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

re = requests.get('https://www.redbubble.com/i/iphone-case/What-A-Time-To-Be-Alive-by-DinoMike/36490886.RIOBD')
        
src = re.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "html.parser")

tags = soup.find_all("span", {"class" : "styles__children--21o3C"})

print(tags)
```

Comment: As I can see from your code, you do only one request. Is it the thing that takes more than a half second?

Comment: this request is just for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple pages to request from, here is a cool library, `tqdm`, which shows a progress bar.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tqdm import tqdm

# set of target URLs
urls = [
    "https://www.redbubble.com/i/iphone-case/What-A-Time-To-Be-Alive-by-DinoMike/36490886.RIOBD",
    ...
]
set_tags = []
# go through the list
for url in tqdm(urls):
    # get request
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    tags = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "styles__children--21o3C"})
    set_tags.append(tags)
```

Comment: can I get the progress as integers like that (15%, 30%, 40%, and so on) ?

Comment: tqdm shows you the progress in real-time.

Comment: I know but is there any ability to get the real-time progress in integers and append these integers in a list?